# One button click fires signal multiple times instead of once

Tags: python, pyside

I'm using pyside and sqlalchemy for a database of contact information.

The setup of sqlalchemy is pretty standard, except for the fact that when I created the session using sessionmaker(), I set `expire_on_commit = False`.

In order to be able to create a new session within a sitting I'm using a sort of refresh button. The problem is every time I use the refresh button, when I try to add a new line/entry, I get 2 or 4 additional entries (with one click), whereas if one gets deleted, all the "copies" are deleted too (they aren't actual copies though because each of them has their own unique id).

```
def refresh(self):

    self.session.close_all()
    self.session = CreateSession(self.username, self.password) #custom method defined elsewhere for creating a session

    self.TableViews() #initializing the table views for pyside

    self.WidgetsToAttributes() #connect widgets of the gui to the sqlalchemy scheme attributes

    self.connectSignals() #connects the qt signals to the appropriate functions in code

    pass
```

(there are also some additional initializations but they are irrelevant here because they only initialize some widgets)

All the above functions are used in other places, for example for the first initialization of the GUI, so what doesn't work here is the combination of the methods. From what I gather, it's the `connectSignals()` method that causes all the trouble. Signals are apparently doubled (sometimes quadrupled) which results in several entries (execution of code) from one click.

What causes that and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call several time a `connect`, your signal will be connected several times to the same slot. One signal will then trigger multiple calls to the slot. I think that's why you get multiple entries in your database.

As a simple example, the code bellow would print two "1" every time the button is clicked:

```
self.button=QtGui.QPushButton("my button")
self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
def on_click(self):
    print("1")
```

---

Signals are automatically disconnected when an object is destroyed. In your case, you destroy `self.session` to create a new one. So every signals directly linked to `self.session` should be destroyed.

But if you have something like this:

```
class myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent=None):
        super(myWidget, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.button=QtGui.QPushButton("add entry")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    def on_click(self):
        self.session.add_an_entry()
```

Then destroying `self.session` is not going to disconnect the signal between the button and the `on_click` function.
So, you can either not call this kind of `connect` multiple time, or you can manually delete the connection with `disconnect`.